# How to add value in array which is present inside objects array?

Tags: javascript

here, I want to update data in such way that if same person with same company comes then it's value of client should come under one array.
input data :

```
const employee = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'BMW'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Volvo'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Mercedes'
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```js
[
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: ['BMW', 'Mercedes']
    },
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Volvo'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in O(n) time. If you're fine with O(n^2) time, I'd suggest using `reduce` (as Mina's answer shows) since it's more straightforward.

```js
const inputs = [{
    name: 'John',
    company: 'abc',
    client: 'BMW'
}, {
    name: 'Jack',
    company: 'abc',
    client: 'Volvo'
}, {
    name: 'John',
    company: 'abc',
    client: 'Mercedes'
}];

const itemsByNameCompany = {};
for (let input of inputs) {
  const nameCompany = `${input.name},${input.company}`;
  itemsByNameCompany[nameCompany] = itemsByNameCompany[nameCompany] || [];
  itemsByNameCompany[nameCompany].push(input);
}

const outputs = [];
for (let key in itemsByNameCompany) {
  const items = itemsByNameCompany[key];
  const clients = items.map(item => item.client);
  const item = {
    ...items[0],
    client: clients.length === 1 ? clients[0] : clients
  };
  outputs.push(item);
}

console.log(outputs);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of way we can do that, `Reduce`, `map`, `forOf` or you can use that as well:

```
let employee = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'BMW'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Volvo'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Mercedes'
    }
];
let employees = {};
employee.forEach(employee => {
    if(employees[employee.name]){
        employees[employee.name].client = [...employees[employee.name].client, employee.client];
    } else {
        employees[employee.name] = { ...employee, client: [employee.client] };
        
    }
});

console.log(employees); // Simple Object group by name
console.log(Object.values(employees)); // Convert to Array
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a function that does this:

- Check if the same name and company combination exists
- If it exists, then update the client property
- If the combination doesn't exist, add it to the same array

```
    const result = [];
    function _addData(obj){
          const index = result.findIndex((item) => 
                item.name === obj.name && item.company === obj.company);
         
      if(index!=-1){
         const client = result[index].client;
        if(Array.isArray(client)){
           client.push(obj.client);
         } else{
                result[index].client = [client, obj.client]; 
          }
       } else{
          result.push(obj);          
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function that checks if the client already is an array. If it is then you can just push the new client. If its a string then you can take the previous value and the new value and write both of them into a new array.

You can do it like this:

```js
const employee = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'BMW'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jack',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Volvo'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        company: 'abc',
        client: 'Mercedes'
    }
]

function addClient(index, client) {
  if (Array.isArray(employee[index].client)) {
    employee[index].client.push(client);
  } else {
    employee[index].client = [employee[index].client, client];
  }
}

addClient(0, 'New Client')
addClient(0, 'New Client2')
addClient(1, 'New Client3')
console.log(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method to group the employees together it they have equal `name` and `company`.

```js
const employees = [
  {
      name: 'John',
      company: 'abc',
      client: 'BMW'
  },
  {
      name: 'Jack',
      company: 'abc',
      client: 'Volvo'
  },
  {
      name: 'John',
      company: 'abc',
      client: 'Mercedes'
  }
  ]
  
  const result = employees.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const itemInAcc = acc.find(i => i.name === item.name && i.company === item.company);
    if (itemInAcc) {
      let client = itemInAcc.client
      itemInAcc.client = [...(Array.isArray(client) ? client : [client]), item.client];
    } else {
      acc.push(item)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  
  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use reduce to group

```
employee.reduce((grouped, next) => {
  if (grouped.some(gItem => gItem.name === next.name && gItem.company === next.company)) {
    grouped = grouped.map(gItem => {
      if (gItem.name === next.name && gItem.company === next.company) {
        gItem.client = Array.isArray(gItem.client) ? [...gItem.client, next.client] : [gItem.client, next.client]
      }
      return gItem
    })
  } else {
    grouped.push(next)
  }
  return grouped
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case you need to create new JSON object to collect filtered data,

This is my simple code just using forEach

```js
const employee = [{
            name: 'John',
            company: 'abc',
            client: 'BMW'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jack',
            company: 'abc',
            client: 'Volvo'
        },
        {
            name: 'John',
            company: 'abc',
            client: 'Mercedes'
        }
    ]
    const newEmployee = [];
    employee.forEach(e => {

        let obj = newEmployee.find(o => o.name === e.name);

        if (obj) {

            if (obj.client instanceof Array) {
                
                obj.client.push(e.client)
            } else {

                obj.client = [e.client]
            }
        } else {

            e.client = [e.client];

            newEmployee.push(e);
        }
    })

    console.log(newEmployee)
```